# What's the name of this connector?

Tags: power-supply, connector, plug

I cannot find the name of those power/charger connectors they have on the electric scooters and "hoverboards".

It seems to be some 3-pin XLR-like plug.

Can anyone help?

[image]

Comment: Some people call it "microphone connector", because this is/was one of the main uses for these connectors: http://www.tme.eu/gb/katalog/microphone-connectors_100378/ Some call it simply "multipole connector".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

its a female multi pin connector - 3 pins

Comment: Just plain simple "multi pin connector"? Seriously? - I thought you'd be kidding me, but I really do find them by this search term. Now I see these "multi pins" go by the names of "aviation plug" or "GX16" too.

Comment: that's true but multi pin will do

Comment: Have to correct myself: It's *not* GX16 but **GX12**.